# Effective mass vs. effective charge

Tags: mass, charge, semiconductor-physics

In a semiconductor the effective mass multiplying the drift velocity is the result of the scattering of electrons off the ions in the crystal. I know that at least in the lowest order approximation the effective mass shows up in the dispersion relationship $E = E_0 + \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m^*}$. But the interaction being electrostatic would it be equally valid to say that its effective interacting *charge* is different from its free space value?

Comment: The effective mass does not come from scattering - it comes from the shape of the band itself.

Comment: Interactions here usually are included by modifications of dielectric constant, not charge.

Comment: @Chong Wang the effective masses of the holes and electrons are different, but the charges are assumed to be the same; how is that represented  in the permittivity?

Comment: @Jon Custer what causes the shape of the band itself if not the interaction between the charged carriers and the lattice?

Comment: That still has nothing to do with scattering, however.

Comment: @Jon Custer scattering = interaction

Comment: No, scattering has a particular meaning in solid state physics.

Comment: @Jon Custer fine, call it interaction not scattering, now can you answer the question?

Comment: The energy vs wave vector states for the bands are the result of solving for the Bloch wave functions for the crystal. At some level this can be thought of as taking atomic orbitals and 'overlapping' them. The effective mass approximation is introduced for the 'nearly free' electron simple approximation, where the band(s) take on a nearly parabolic shape. In real crystals there is no particular reason for the bands to be parabolic, and inspection of real crystal band structures will show that they are not, in general.